# what is the cli command for creating directives in a specific component?

Tags: angular-cli

Hello all  I need a small help me . In Angular 14 what is the cli command for creating  directives in a specific component?

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation you can find here : https://angular.io/cli/generate#directive-command

You simply need to navigate to the location you want the directive to be created, and then use the following command :

```
ng generate directive my-directive-name
```

Comment: Oh so there is no specific cli command for specific component? Like if I want to  create a component in a particular module  then we write   ng generate component  modulename/componentname